# Need to login/ register during Spring Web-Flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a web flow defined with 4 steps in it. I have also spring security configured properly.

In the last step, I need to save the user's order which requires a user account. Therefore, I need to ensure the user is logged in before the last step is executed. So what I want is:
- users that are already logged will smoothly move to the last step
- users that are not logged in, will have to go to our register/ login page after which they will be redirected back to continue the flow.

Note: the first steps do NOT require to be logged in (or registered). Only the last step.

How do I redirect back to the last step after login/ register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for login. Just add:

```
 <secured attributes="ROLE_USER" />
```

To the flow element you want to secure. See [Spring WebFlow Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/ch08s03.html)

I have not solved it for register yet. As we need to re-enter the flow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reuse RequestCache (that is used by Spring Security itself). During request processing of the last page you need to do:

```
requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);
```

See `ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(...)` for example.

If your login page is configured correctly then Spring Security will add automatically `RequestCacheAwareFilter` to corresponding filer chain. `RequestCacheAwareFilter` will do the trick.

**EDIT.** It must work in Spring MVC environment. I am not sure about Spring Web-Flow (may be there is higer level framework support for this case)